# Add a check box to not add the start menu icons

Tags: inno-setup, shortcut, startmenu

So this is probably really simple, and I've been looking and looking for an example, but can't seem to find one.

I just need to add a check box to select the option NOT to create a start menu shortcut to the screen where it says, "Select Start Menu Folder - Where should Setup place the program's shortcuts?".  Just not sure how to do this.  Help would be vastly appreciated.

Here's my code so far:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Launcher
AppVersion=1.1
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Launcher
DefaultGroupName=My Launcher
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\myLauncher.exe
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes

[InstallDelete]
Type: files;  Name: "{app}\myLauncher.exe";

[Files]
Source: "myLauncher.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "QtCore4.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "QtGui4.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "QtNetwork4.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "QtSql4.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"


[Icons]
Name: "{group}\My Launcher"; Filename: "{app}\myLauncher.exe"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the `[Setup]` section, try adding this to the end:

```
AllowNoIcons=yes
```

See [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_allownoicons) for the official documentation on this property.

Comment: Thank you very much, so simple.  What I don't understand is why its so hard to find that little bit of information in their support guide.  Thanks Dale!

Comment: For anyone interested here's the documentation: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_allownoicons.htm

Comment: Also presented as a nice checkbox when creating a setup through the wizard.